# Evaluating $\sum_{m=j_2-j}^{j_1} \frac{(j_1+m)!(j_2+j-m)!}{(j_1-m)!(j_2-j+m)!}$ using combinatorial identities

Tags: combinatorics, summation, combinatorial-proofs

I'm trying to prove the identity
$$
\sum_{m=j_2-j}^{j_1} \frac{(j_1+m)!(j_2+j-m)!}{(j_1-m)!(j_2-j+m)!}=
\frac{(j+j_1-j_2)!(j-j_1+j_2)!(j+j_1+j_2+1)!}{(j_1+j_2-j)!(2j+1)!} \tag{1}
$$
where $2j_1,2j_2\in \mathbb{Z}^+$ and $\vert 2j_1-2j_2\vert\le 2j\le 2(j_1+j_2)$.  The summation over $m$ is in steps of $1$ from $j-j_2$ to $j_1$. This summation occurs as part of a normalization condition on $su(2)$ Clebsch-Gordan coefficients.

Apparently to prove this one must use the binomial identities 
\begin{align}
\sum_{x} {a\choose x}{b\choose c-x}&={a+b\choose c} \tag{2}\\
{u \choose v}&= (-1)^v {v-u-1\choose v}\, .  \tag{3}
\end{align}

I found in [Eq.(6.1) of this volume](http://www.math.wvu.edu/~gould/Vol.4.PDF) that (2) is known as the integral Vandermonde Convolution.  (3) can be found as Eq.(2.1) of [this paper.](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1105.3689.pdf)

My difficulty is in seeing the relevance of (2) since the left hand side of
(1) contains the summation index $m$ in the numerator and the denominator while the dummy index in (2) appears only in the denominator.

I have to deal with several variants of this summation formula so any help in bridging the gap between the left and right hand side of (1) would be appreciated.

Comment: If $j_2-j_1 < j$ then, at $m=-j_1$, the denominator contains the factorial of $j_2-j-j_1$, which is strictly less than zero. That is a little bit odd. Can you please clarify the interpretation of the factorial of negative numbers, or perhaps see if the bounds of summation need to be changed?

Comment: @ZachTeitler Good catch.  Fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Please note that if this answer is not as rigorous as you may like then I urge you to fill in the details.*

I'm thinking you can rearrange $(1)$ into the form

$$\sum_{m=j_2-j}^{j_1} \frac{(j_1+m)!}{(j_2-j+m)!(j+j_1-j_2)!}\frac{(j_2+j-m)!}{(j_1-m)!(j-j_1+j_2)!}\stackrel{?}{=}
\frac{(j+j_1+j_2+1)!}{(j_1+j_2-j)!(2j+1)!}$$

or

$$\sum_{m=j_2-j}^{j_1} \binom{j_1+m}{j_2-j+m}\binom{j_2+j-m}{j_1-m}\stackrel{?}{=}
\frac{(j+j_1+j_2+1)!}{(j_1+j_2-j)!(2j+1)!}\tag{*}$$

Using $(3)$ on the left hand side summation

$$\sum_{m=j_2-j}^{j_1} (-1)^{j_2-j+m}\binom{j_2-j_1-j-1}{j_2-j+m}(-1)^{j_1-m}\binom{j_1-j_2-j-1}{j_1-m}$$

gives

$$(-1)^{j_1+j_2-j}\sum_{m=j_2-j}^{j_1} \binom{j_2-j_1-j-1}{j_2-j+m}\binom{j_1-j_2-j-1}{j_1-m}$$

then call $x=j_2-j+m$ and $c=j_1+j_2-j$ so we have from $(2)$

$$(-1)^{j_1+j_2-j}\sum_{x=2(j_2-j)}^{j_2+j_1-j} \binom{j_2-j_1-j-1}{x}\binom{j_1-j_2-j-1}{c-x}=\binom{-2j-2}{j_1+j_2-j}\tag{**}$$

Now use $(3)$ on the right hand side of $(\text{**})$

$$\begin{align}(-1)^{j_1+j_2-j}\sum_{x=2(j_2-j)}^{j_2+j_1-j} \binom{j_2-j_1+j+1}{x}\binom{j_2-j_1+j-1}{c-x}=&(-1)^{j_1+j_2-j}\binom{j+j_1+j_2+1}{j_1+j_2-j}\\[1ex]\implies\sum_{x=2(j_2-j)}^{j_2+j_1-j} \binom{j_2-j_1+j+1}{x}\binom{j_2-j_1+j-1}{c-x}&=\frac{(j+j_1+j_2+1)!}{(j_1+j_2-j)!(2j+1)!}\end{align}$$

which is the right hand side of $(\text{*})$.

Notice I am playing fast and loose with limits on the Vandermonde summation. I'll leave that to you to make sure they obey $(2)$.

Comment: Wow!  This is promising and I'll check it out within 48hrs.  Thanks.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero okay, let me know if you spot any errors.

Comment: @N.Shales: Despite playing fast, as you said, the essentials are correct. (+1)

Comment: Thank you @MarkusScheuer it's good to have some confirmation. Much appreciated! (+1)

Comment: @N.Shales: You're welcome! :-)

Answer (score 4):

Here is a streamlined variant.

> The following is valid for integers $j_1,j_2,j$ with $0\leq j_2-j\leq j_1$.
>   \begin{align*}
> \frac{1}{(j+j_1-j_2)!(j-j_1+j_2)!}\sum_{m=j_2-j}^{j_1}\frac{(j_1+m)!(j_2+j-m)!}{(j_1-m)!(j_2-j+m)!}=
> \frac{(j+j_1+j_2+1)!}{(j_1+j_2-j)!(2j+1)!}
> \end{align*}

We obtain

> \begin{align*}
> &\color{blue}{\frac{1}{(j+j_1-j_2)!(j-j_1+j_2)!}\sum_{m=j_2-j}^{j_1}\frac{(j_1+m)!(j_2+j-m)!}{(j_1-m)!(j_2-j+m)!}}\\
> &\qquad=\sum_{m=j_2-j}^{j_1}\binom{j_1+m}{j_2-j+m}\binom{j_2+j-m}{j_1-m}\tag{1}\\
> &\qquad=\sum_{m=j_2-j}^{j_1}\binom{-j_1+j_2-j-1}{j_2-j+m}(-1)^{j_2-j+m}\binom{-j_2-j+j_1-1}{j_1-m}(-1)^{j_1-m}\tag{2}\\
> &\qquad=(-1)^{j_1+j_2-j}\sum_{m=0}^{j_1+j_2-j}\binom{-j_1+j_2-j-1}{m}\binom{-j_2-j+j_1-1}{j_1+j_2-j-m}\tag{3}\\
> &\qquad=(-1)^{j_1+j_2-j}\binom{-2j-2}{j_1+j_2-j}\tag{4}\\
> &\qquad\color{blue}{=\binom{j_1+j_2+j+1}{j_1+j_2-j}}\tag{5}
> \end{align*}
>   and the claim follows.

*Comment:*

- In (1) we collect the factorials and write them as binomial coefficients.
- In (2) we apply twice the binomial identity
  \begin{align*}
  \binom{-p}{q}=\binom{p+q-1}{q}(-1)^q
  \end{align*}
- In (3) we shift the index to start from $m=0$.
- In (4) we apply *[Vandermonde's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity)*.
- In (5) we apply again the identity as in (2).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed solution.  I see that you and @N.Shales did not use my (2) but rather and slightly different form of it.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero: You're welcome! I think, there's in fact no  difference. When looking at (3) in my answer we have: $a=-j_1+j_2-j-1, b=-j_2-j+j_1-1, c=j_1+j_2-j$ and $a+b=-2j-2$ in accordance with your expression (2).

Comment: BTW: the colors are a brilliant idea (pardon the pun)!

Comment: @ZeroTheHero: :-)